# Codenameone theming sidemenu

Tags: themes, codenameone, hamburger-menu

How to change the background color and set the UIID of the sidemenu (Hamburger menu)? I changed all of the items from theme.res but no luck.
I use the new sidebar API:

```
f.getToolbar().addMaterialCommandToSideMenu("Google", FontImage.MATERIAL_WEB, e -> Display.getInstance().execute("https://www.google.com"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the component inspector to get the right UIID to change the aspect of the side menu.
I don't know what you're looking for changes but there's UIID like :

**SideNavigationPanel**
   **StatusBarSideMenu**
   **SoftButton**

Comment: Also in the designer you not have a side menu, so if you open it and then press `Add` these UIID's will appear next to the top.